# Can I use epoxy resin to fix cracks in potable water equipment?

Tags: water, repair, leak, appliances, epoxy

Recently I've noticed some issues in my old countertop water distiller:

[image: countertop water distiller with plastic boiler cover]

There were several cracks in the plastic top cover of the boiler. To fix it, I've tried some epoxy resin (brand name "Durepoxi") similar to Araldite. The reason was:

- According to the manufacturer specifications, it can handle temperatures from -50°C to +150°C. Therefore it should handle the temperatures inside the boiler.
- It is used very often to fix water pipes. Therefore, **at first**, it should not be toxic.

However, now that I've "fixed" the distiller, the water coming out from it is tasting awful. To remove this taste, I'm using ceramic + activated charcoal filter, which improves a lot this issue.

**Questions**

1. Is it safe to use epoxy resin in this case? Any health risk?
2. After the aforementioned filtration with ceramic and activated charcoal, is it safe to drink the water coming out from this distiller?
3. What would be a better approach to fix this distiller? High temperature silicone?

Comment: Does the product labelling clearly state that it's safe for drinking water and/or food handling systems?  If not, then it should NOT be considered safe.

Comment: The unmodified product is safe to drink its water. However, this is no longer the case since I've used some epoxy resin to fix its broken interior.

Comment: @jwh20 Therefore, the issue is: is it safe to use this product with the aforementioned modifications? (ie: with epoxy resin inside to fix some cracks)

Comment: I'm talking about the EPOXY not the water distiller.

Comment: @jwh20 That is the problem. The manufacturer specification doesn't mention its hazardous for the cured state. The specs only mention in the uncured state, which in this case is toxic.

Comment: @jwh20 Considering that the manufacturer clearly states that the epoxy can be used in water pipes, it is somewhat reasonable to expect that such epoxy is not toxic. However, I can not guarantee for sure that, reason why I'm posting these questions.

Comment: Where do you see that this product states "safe for drinking water systems"?  I'm not finding it for Araldite.  But you said your product is from a different manufacturer.

Comment: @jwh20 As I've mentioned, the manufacturer doesn't say explicitly it is "safe for drinking water systems". However, it does say that it can be used in water systems.

Comment: What is their definition of "water systems"?

Comment: @jwh20 Actually they only provide instructions on how to fix water pipes in general. There is no formal definition of which kind of water pipes or water systems.

Comment: I am not concerned about "pipes" vs. "system".  I'm concerned about "water" vs. "drinking water".  It seems you are as well.  If this were my system, I'd replace or remove the distiller rather than subject myself to whatever might leech out of the epoxy at high temperature while in long-term contact with drinking water.

Comment: It's not at all clear whether the part or the place where you are patching is in contact with the water or not.

Comment: @jwh20 It is a standard countertop water distiller. Therefore, the water at rest should not contact the boiler cover. However, when the water starts boiling, things gets very agitated inside there and water (both as liquid and as gas) will contact such cover (not submerged, but in splashes).

Comment: Contact the manufacturer to see if you can purchase a replacement for the broken part. Then determine if the replacement part cost vs the cost of a whole new system is worth it _to you_. I think, now that you've already applied a _potentially_ toxic epoxy to the currently broken part, that will be your only option. Also, I have "water pipes" in my house that I have zero concern over repairing with a toxic substance - they're in my drainage system and I'm _never_ going to consume water that's flowed through them...

Comment: Voting to close as opinion-based. Either the manufacturer has a statement about potable water use or they don't. Also, just "epoxy". Epoxy resin is one component of a multi-part system. It's like saying "concrete cement".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120995/discussion-on-question-by-dereck-gardner-can-i-use-epoxy-resin-to-fix-cracks-in).